# c++ - arithmetic operations with a very very large numbers

Tags: c++, integer

I need to write a program that performs arithmetic operations
But I have to do it with really really big numbers for example
2837456897658923563425345 + 23784623874623874682736478236

Because the numbers themselves are so large, I keep them as a string
I just can not figure out how I can do simple things like adding and subtracting when I can not move those numbers to variables because they're so big

Comment: Propose YOUR attempt to solve the problem

Comment: There's a number of 3rd party libraries you can use to deal with _big integers_.

Comment: You do it the way you were taught in primary school, one digit at a time. It gets much simpler if you store the numbers backwards.

Comment: [Tom's fast math](https://github.com/libtom/tomsfastmath)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to use external libraries such as GNU GMP, but it's better if you use them. However, you still can do such stuff.

Let's sum 15467985611234679845178946510379845612546541238708 and 67467985611412679845878946783212365212043542388978. The result will be of course 829359712464735970057893294422108246883627686 and we can see that easily. (lol)

Now, let's jump to code. Start by dividing number into smaller pieces. Let's say 5 10s and do the math on them. Now let's see what the output says.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long bigNumber1[5] = { 1546798561, 1234679845, 1789465103, 7984561254, 6541238708 };
    long bigNumber2[5] = { 6746798561, 1412679845, 8789467832, 1236521204, 3542388978 };

    long tempSum = 0;
    int carry = 0;
    long sum[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        tempSum = bigNumber1[i] + bigNumber2[i] + carry;

        if (i == 0)
            sum[i] = tempSum;
        else
            sum[i] = tempSum % 1000000000;

        carry = tempSum / 1000000000;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << sum[i];
}
```

Output:

```
829359712464735970057893294422108246883627686
```

Seems like it's working. :)

**BUT** still, you can use a basic library such as **GNU GMP** to achieve this way easier.

Good luck and have fun!

**APPROACH 2:** Since you've asked to sum different length nums too. I made some different arithmetics.

This time let's sum,

`15467985611234679845178946510379845612546541238708`
`+__67467985611412679845878946783212365212043542388`
`15535453596846092525024825457163057977758584781096`

Here's the code for it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1[255], num2[255], sum[255];
    char s1[255], s2[255];
    int l1, l2;

    cin >> s1 >> s2;

    for (l1 = 0; s1[l1] != '\0'; l1++)
        num1[l1] = s1[l1] - '0';

    for (l2 = 0; s2[l2] != '\0'; l2++)
        num2[l2] = s2[l2] - '0';

    int carry = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int i = l1 - 1;
    int j = l2 - 1;
    for (; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--, k++)
    {
        sum[k] = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) % 10;
        carry = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) / 10;
    }
    if (l1 > l2)
    {
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            sum[k++] = (num1[i] + carry) % 10;
            carry = (num1[i--] + carry) / 10;
        }
    }
    else if (l1 < l2)
    {
        while (j >= 0)
        {
            sum[k++] = (num2[j] + carry) % 10;
            carry = (num2[j--] + carry) / 10;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (carry > 0)
            sum[k++] = carry;
    }

    for (k--; k >= 0; k--)
        cout << sum[k];

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
15535453596846092525024825457163057977758584781096
```

as expected. Now you can pretty much sum anything you want to. I suggest you to understand the code.

Enjoy it!

Comment: thanks,but what if the numbers are not symmetrical? Say and I can not divide them into small numbers of 5 10s evenly?

Comment: @user8093201 I'm writing a code for that. Hang tight. It'll work with pretty much any number.

Comment: @user8093201 check approach 2. This time it works with pretty much anything you put in. Enjoy it.

If this answers your question don't forget to press on the tick icon next to my answer. It'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a bignum library - like for example [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org).

C++ can deal with fairly large numbers - enough for most purposes. But for larger numbers than C++ native types can handle you either need to write your own code to do math on  those or just use an existing library (recommended).